# Error when extracting comments in my facebook page through laravel app using Facebook graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to extract comments in my facebook page. For that I made a Facebook graph app. I can extract the comments in Graph API explorer using `{page-id}?fields=posts.limit(1000){comments}` query. [image: View of graph explorer]

But when I tried to get comments through a laravel app, it gives me an error. The code in laravel app is

```
$fb = new Facebook([
        'app_id' => getenv('FACEBOOK_APP_ID'),
        'app_secret' => getenv('FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'),
        'access_token'    => getenv('FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN'),
        'default_graph_version' => 'v3.3',
        ]);

        $accessToken=getenv('FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN');
    try {

        $response = $fb->get('/{page-id}?fields=posts.limit(1000){comments}',$accessToken);

      } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseExcepti9on $e) {
        $e->getMessage();
        exit;
      } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        $e->getMessage();
        exit;
      }
      $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
```

Error is

> (#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.

This is how my graph permission and features page looks. [image: Graph permission and features page]What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You did not use a page access token, so the API does not know you have admin access to the page.

Comment: FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN variable is the page's access token

Comment: So what info does it show when you debug the token?

Comment: App ID, Type, Page ID, App-Scoped User ID, Issued, Expires, Data Access Expires, Valid, Origin, Scopes

Comment: Double check your app id & secret, and the page id actually used. You should only get this error if you are not using a page access token for the page.